# Animate scrollTop on scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, scroll

I have a custom slider. And I want to do a such thing. When user scrolls down it should animate scroll down to next slide, and during this animation user should not be able to scroll. But I have a problem. Scroll event is fired multiple times, and after one animation is done, second one is started, and etc.

Here is my code sample

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){
  if($scrolling){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
})

$(window).on('mousewheel', function(event){
    $scrolling = true
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 'my position here' }, {done: function(){ $scrolling = false; } }, 1000)
});
```

What I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want it to scroll a full page height, you can use [One Page Scroll](http://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll) or [FullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/). Otherwise you would likely use `.animate` and `.stop` and add/subtract a set value of how far you want it to scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control everything from the `mousewheel` event alone..

```
var $scrolling = false;
$(window).on('mousewheel', function(event){
  if (!$scrolling){
    $scrolling = true;
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 'my position here' }, {done: function(){ $scrolling = false; } }, 1000);
  }
});
```